# How to get a grouped mean rather than an overall mean with plyr in R

Tags: r

I am getting an overall mean value for my dataset whereas I would like it per repName

Here is a dataset example

```
repName divergence
L2a 0.013
L2a 0.114
L2a 0.294
L2a 0.338
L2b 0.284
L2b 0.306
MIR 0.282
MIR 0.242
MIR 0.181
MIR3    0.235
MIR3    0.23
MIR3    0.346
MIR3    0.331
MIR3    0.279
MIR3    0.303
MIR3    0.095
```

Here is the dataset I want

```
repName divergence
L2a 0.18975
MIR3    0.259857143
L2b 0.295
MIR 0.235
```

and here is my attempt at the code

```
library(dplyr)
GroupedTableProportion <- mydiv %>% group_by(repName) %>% summarise(divergence)
```

but this just gives me

```
mean(divergence)
0.1887634
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell `summarise` what to do

```
mydiv %>% group_by(repName) %>% summarise(mean(divergence))
```

Answer (score 0):

Other options include `aggregate` from base R

```
aggregate(divergence~repName, mydiv, mean)
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydiv)[, list(divergence=mean(divergence)), by = repName]
```